# Compare keys of dictionary with values of List and return all the matching values including duplicates

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, compare

I have a Dictionary<string, string> and another List. What I am trying to achieve is a linq query to compare dictionary with list and get all values present in the dictionary(comparing list with key in dictionary) matching with the list including duplicate values in the list. Eg, I am using

```
        Dictionary<string, string> key = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        key.Add("RC", "rick castolle");
        key.Add("MS", "Robet sam");
        key.Add("VC", "John David");
        key.Add("KS", "Kelly Thomson");

        List<string> a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("JC"); a.Add("KS"); a.Add("RC"); a.Add("KS");

        var output = key.Where(s => a.Contains(s.Key)).Select(s => new object[] {s.Value }).ToList();
```

It returns output as
rick castolle
Kelly Thomson

But expected output for me is
rick castolle
Kelly Thomson
Kelly Thomson

Since their are three repeated items for Ks in the list.
How do i achieve my output to get the duplicate values which are present in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make the query from the other side (the list).

```
a.Where(i => key.ContainsKey(i)).Select(i => key[i])
```

But it will be more effective if you can use foreach, where you'll be checking the dictionary only once for every item:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var i in a)
{
    if (key.TryGetValue(i, out var val)
        result.Add(val);
}
```